# Latex new command

Tags: latex, macros

I would like to define a new command like this

```
\newcommand{\bob}[1]{\excerpt \begin{lstlisting} {#1} \end{lstlisting}}
```

and then use it like this

```
\bob{abcd}
```

but i get the following error in latex.

```
text dropped after begin of listing latex
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the following

```
\newcommand{\boy}[1] {{%
\begin{Verbatim} %
{ #1 } %
\end{Verbatim} }}
```

And I still get an error when I try to use it.

```
\boy{abc}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [`\newenvironment` macro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX).

In this case you would use it like this

```
\newenvironment{bob}{%
\excerpt \begin{lstlisting}}{%
\end{lstlisting}}
```

and later

```
\begin{bob}
abcd
\end{bob}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{listing}` environment is special and magical; it can't be used inside a command like that.  Changing to a `\newenvironment` setup as described by dmckee should work.  If you can't make that work, check out the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) package.

Comment: I tried the fancyvrb and it did not help solve the problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try the lstnewenvironment of the listings package.